# How to pass the state of the page to other React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how I can pass a status from one page to another page for if used in the other way.

My first page `Body.js` (Which I handle the state):

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Body.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import User from './User';

class Body extends React.Component {
    constructor (){
        super();
        
        this.state ={
            employee:[],
            employeeCurrent:[],
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee').then(
        response=>this.setState({employee: response.data})
    )
}

getName = () => {
    const {employee} = this.state;
    return employee.map(name=> <Link className='link' to={`/user/${name.name}`}> <div onClick={()=>this.add(name)} key={name.id} className='item'>  <img className='img' src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.name}`}></img> <h1 className='name'> {name.name} </h1></div> </Link>)
}

add = (name) => {
    const nam = name;
    this.state.employeeCurrent.push(nam)
    console.log(this.state.employeeCurrent)
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className='body'>
            {this.getName()}
        </div>
    )
}
}


export default Body;
```

My second page which I want to get the state called `employeeCurrent`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Body from './Body';


class User extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        
        this.props ={
            employeeCurrent:[],
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div >
        {this.props.employeeCurrent}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default User;
```

I'm using the React Router, it looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import User from './User';

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <div className='router'>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/user/:id" component={User}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

My project is:
Home page, where you have users, obtained from the API, all users have attributes (name, age, city and country). Saved in `employeeCurrent` variable:
[image]

What I want is: grab these attributes from the clicked user and play on the user page:
[image]

Someone would can help me PLEASE?????

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087631/how-to-pass-a-state-without-to-import-component-reactjs/50087796#50087796

Comment: @SteveBanton don't think that's right here, since he's using react-router.

Comment: @Colin my answer also uses react-router - unless I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: @SteveBanton Many thanks for your response there, I visualized, tried to do more did not work, I'll try again.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html if steve's answer doesn't suit you

Comment: no problem - give it a shot, let me know how it goes. The pattern has worked well in production for me, and I believe it should solve your particular problem.

Comment: @SteveBanton The code passed there, I create a new `.js` file? Or where is my route?

Comment: i also think @Deryck's mention of context would be an excellent option if using react 16.3+

Comment: You'll have routes.js, DashboardContainer.js (with code I included - react-router's `Route` is inside that component), Body.js, and User.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I explained earlier, you need to lift the state up:

**AppRouter** (holds the state and passes it to children)

```
class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    employeeCurrent: [],
    employee: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
      .then(response => this.setState({ employee: response.data }));
  }

  add = name => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const copy = prevState.employeeCurrent.slice();
      copy.push(name);
      return {
        employeeCurrent: copy
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="router">
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={props => (
              <Home
                {...props}
                add={this.add}
                employee={this.state.employee}
                currentEmployee={this.state.currentEmployee}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/user/:id"
            component={props => (
              <User
                {...props}
                employee={this.state.employee}
                currentEmployee={this.state.currentEmployee}
              />
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**Body and User** (receive parent state as props together with updater functions):

```
class Body extends React.Component {
  getName = () => {
    const { employee, add } = this.props;
    return employee.map(name => (
      <Link className="link" to={`/user/${name.name}`}>
        {" "}
        <div onClick={() => add(name)} key={name.id} className="item">
          {" "}
          <img
            className="img"
            src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.name}`}
          />{" "}
          <h1 className="name"> {name.name} </h1>
        </div>{" "}
      </Link>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="body">{this.getName()}</div>;
  }
}

class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // you will need to map employeeCurrent somehow
    return <div>{this.props.employeeCurrent}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend, very much thanks for your help. 1 question.. Is it API Context? If not, what is ??

Comment: Giving error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Pass employee to Body as prop

Comment: Yes,  i did this now.

Comment: Tomasz, i am doing:
`return <div>{this.props.employeeCurrent.map((teste)=>teste.id)}</div>;` in the User.js and be that error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, you know that can be?

Comment: I put a console.log and it is returning undefined

Comment: It is because was `currentEmployee`, corrected for `employeeCurrent`

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, you helped me a lot. <3

Comment: @Jota awesome!!